# update labels based on selection with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down selector and form fields below. I need to be able to display form labels and corresponding form fields based on selected option.

What is the best way to implement this: prepare possible labels and fields and forms elements and store them in hidden divs and then show/hide based on selection?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#mySelector').change(function(){            
         $('.opt').hide();
         $('#' + $(this).val()).toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<select id="mySelector">
   <option value="o1">Car details
   <option value="o2">Boat details
   <option value="o3">Train details
</select>

<div id="o1" class="opt">
    <label for="f1_1">Car speed</label>
    <input id="f1_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="f1_2">Car color</label>
    <input id="f1_2" type="text">
</div>

<div id="o2" class="opt">
    <label for="f2_1">Boat size</label>
    <input id="f2_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="f2_2">Boat weight</label>
    <input id="f2_2" type="text">
</div>

<div id="o3" class="opt">
    <label for="f3_1">Train length</label>
    <input id="f3_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <label for="f3_2">Train cargo</label>
    <input id="f3_2" type="text">
</div>
```

I assume jQuery is the best way to go...

Also, I will display this 3 times, once for each option. I need some sort of mechanist to prevent selecting the same option that has been selected above. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by **updating** them? Update them to what value?

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of word -- display appropriate field, not update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'weight' of these elements is light then putting them in your page and dynamically toggling which is visible is not a bad idea. Otherwise, you probably should fetch the content via ajax.

```
$('#o1').show()  // This will display the 'o1' div
$('#o1').hide()  // This will hide the 'o1' div
```

I would probably add a class (maybe 'info' to each of the divs). That way you can use

```
.info {display: none; }
```

to initially hide the elements and

```
$('.info').hide() // this will hide all the elements.
```

If you need to use ajax, you probably will need a placeholder div...

```
<div id='placeholder'></div>
```

and use

```
$('#placeholder').load(url)
```

to dynamically fetch the html.

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: Hmm, never thought about fetching from another file. Great idea -- I won't have to worry which form fields are submitted and they won't show in source of the of the page if someone decides to take a peek. Do I need some sort of class to do AJAX?

Comment: If you don't mind the page loading experience just make it simple. Do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/HcADk/2/.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to loading from an external document. Since it is handled with AJAX the page won't be re-loading, right?

Comment: The jsFiddle example doesn't have to use ajax. I have updated it with more information: http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/HcADk/3/. You have two options: non-ajax (load the page directly) and ajax. Both will work. However, I recommend the non-ajax approach first. It is less complex and until the complexity is necessary...better to keep it out.